# Gson parse regex value from json string

Tags: java, json, gson

I receive below string from a message queue, with no double quote;

```
{
    tableName:STUDENT,
    columns: [{
        name: PARENT_PHONE,
        regex:{
            regexCode:PHONE,
            regexValue:[0-9\\-\\+]{9,15}
            }
        }]
}
```

This is the string that I try to parse it to an object as below;

```
TableDefinition tableDefinition = gson.fromJson(tableJson, TableDefinition.class);
```

Of course it's throwing an exception like;

```
Expected a string but was "BEGIN_ARRAY" at line ...
```

I understand that `regexValue` should start with a valid character not with `[`, then I write a custom deserializer in order to parse regexValue property.

Now it is throw MalformedJsonException and debug breakpoint not even stop in custom deserializer method;

```
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated array at line 1 column 325 path $.columns[0].regex.regexValue[1]
```

As exception showed us, Gson still recognize regexValue as an array.

How to tell to Gson that regexValue is a string? How to deal such a situation?

Answer (score -1):

You can't write a custom deserializer to a malformed JSON. If it's malformed then it's not a JSON anymore and Gson can't make any assumptions about a random string. Best bet would be to fix what is sent to the queue and if thats not doable then you would have to fix the currently-malformed-but-to-be-JSON while it's still a string.

Comment: So, I understand that I can extract it without gson, just extract from string? but it is not effective and seems clear,  also just for information I don't have to use gson, jackson is an alternative.

Comment: The library does not matter. Point is that what you are given is not JSON. It looks kinda like JSON, but it's not as it does not follow the JSON standard. So no library could ever handle this. Custom converters are meant to parse special objects out of otherwise correct JSON. So you could try to fix it when it's still a string, but yes you are right: it might not be very effective and it's error prone.

Comment: Throw your raw input into https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com. If it's something you are able to handle with any known library, you will get a properly formatted JSON with no errors back. If not, then it's just a String which no library can handle.

Comment: Another way to think about it is if the given input is not pretty-formatted. It's all on one line. How would any library know when the regexValue's value ends and another part of the JSON begins?

Comment: Yes, it is not pretty-formatted. I just wrote like that for readability. But, gson can handle if there is no regexValue in the string, so I wonder maybe there is a way to do it with regexValue property.